# How to list my recently updated apps

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I would like to be able to see a list of my apps sorted by the date the app was last updated. Descending order is preferred, but honestly I'll take anything.

One use case: Earlier today I had two apps show they needed an update. Neither was one that I use daily, but both were important enough to me that I knew I wanted to update. Unfortunately, my phone crashed shortly after the update and thus the notifications are gone. I cannot for the life of me remember what both apps were. (I blame my advancing age. I remembered one of them.) I know I wanted to check out the changes, but since I've no idea what app it was, I don't know where to look.

I *could* open up every one of my apps in the Play Store and look at the updated date, but I've get well over two hundred apps on here and that is impractical.

Do you have a technique or know of an app that would help me?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to show up if you go to the Play Store app, and go to `My Apps`?

Comment: No. They're only listed alphabetically and no option to change the sort. There's no update date shown. Same with the web app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of version 4.3.10, [the Google Play Store now has a "Recently updated" section under "My apps"](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/08/05/download-latest-google-play-store-4-3-10-with-new-recently-updated-section-combined-update-notifications-new-episode-notifications-and-more-teardown/), which is ultimately what I wanted.

Comment: Any indication of what 'recently' actually means? My mail client has recently started chewing through battery power at an extraordinary rate, and I'm trying to work out if this is some mail/network related thing, or a new version of the app.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Elixir 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.elixir).

If you go to `applications`, you could sort it by update time.

[image: Elixier screenshot (click for larger variant)]
<sup>Elixier screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Yep, that gives me what I want. This is an awfully heavy-weight application to have for something so simple, though. I also don't like that it's offering me the option to move apps to the SD card when my device doesn't have an SD card.

Comment: @user1 Hopefully you'll find more use for Elixir. I use it to give me a home screen with 7x7 icons / shortcuts. Plus a whole load of other functions.

Comment: Perhaps. I've not deleted the app yet. I'll see what else it can do.

Answer (score 1):

[List My Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.onyxbits.listmyapps) does this. Though you might need some script-fu to sort the output by date.

Comment: That's useful. Adding ${lastupdated}, putting some pipes between the fields, and importing into a spreadsheet gives me what I was looking for, more or less.

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the answers here seem partial or outdated, I suggest to try [Total Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander) app - where you can find the `Installed Apps` section, and order it by date:

[image: Screenshot based on the official app page in Google Play app store]