# Date and Time when my App was Updated

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates, facebook

In relation to this question, [How to list my recently updated apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38973/how-to-list-my-recently-updated-apps?newreg=fbd4032c7d6b4a289c175f539b11005b), how can i know the exact time and date my app was actually updated? I was browsing Facebook earlier today, then after a couple hours, I re-opened the app and found that my account was logged out. I suspect that my app auto-updated for some reason and caused my account to be logged off.

Comment: `adb shell "dumpsys package"` will include those details. My little tool [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) uses that when generating a device documentation.

Comment: @Izzy, I don't have access to the `adb` command-line because i unrooted my phone, any other method that you know? thanks!

Comment: You don't need root for ADB. Though it helps for additional information, it's not required to obtain those details. Please see our [adb tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) for some background.